# Function that return =G that indent all file VimL

Tags: vim, neovim

Is it possible to create a function like that in vim that works? xD

```
function !Reindent ()
  return =G "that going to 'showcmd' and gonna prompted out
endfunction
```

I want to call this every time a buffer are read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a function you need only an `autocmd` that will be triggered whenever you read your file into a buffer:

```
autocmd BufRead * normal! =G
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it xD